# Parse json string array returned from c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json

I am returning a JSON array string from c#, which is a list of classes I want to read county element in a class and add it to a js array. How can I parse this string?

```
{"d":"[{\"county\":\"PA\",\"state\":\"Mountur\"},{\"county\":\"PA\",\"state\":\" Beaver\"}]"}
```

Comment: Show us how have you tried to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The `d` property is itself JSON, so you need to parse that separately from the response to give you an array of objects which you can work with, something like this:

```js
var response = {
  "d": "[{\"county\":\"PA\",\"state\":\"Mountur\"},{\"county\":\"PA\",\"state\":\" Beaver\"}]"
}

var arr = JSON.parse(response.d);
arr.forEach(function(obj) {
  console.log(obj.county + ' ' + obj.state);
});

console.log(arr);
```